# pytest: AttributeError: Test class object has no attribute?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing pytest for the following class

```
class DService:
    def get_file_list(self, catalog):
        '''Get the files of a product catalog'''
```

The pytest code is

```
@pytest.fixture
def d_service():
    c = DService(username, password)    
    return c  # tried yield too

class TestDService:
    def test_get_file_list(d_service):
        print(type(d_service))  
        files = d_service.get_file_list('')
        print(files)
```

However, pytest got error?

> AttributeError: 'TestDService' object has no attribute 'get_file_list'

Answer (score 3):

First variable for test methods must be `self`:

`def test_get_file_list(self, d_service)`

https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class

Comment: Thanks. I just removed `class TestDService` to make it work.